# What is the coding character shurtcut on Windows?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters, characters

I can use <kbd>`</kbd> character with copy-paste from **charmap** but i want use with shortcut on my keyboard. What can i do? What is shortcut of this character on **Windows 8**? My keyboard is: Turkish Windows 8 Notebook Keyboard(with num pad). Its view: [image: turkish notebook keyboard]

## **(!)** PROBLEM IS SOLVED

Shorcut for this character in Turkish Q Keyboard: <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> *(comma)*

Comment: It depends what keyboard you are using, which you haven't said. On a UK keyboard it has its own key, to the left of the "1" key. On other keyboards it is an accent (diacritical), which needs to be followed by a space to produce the independent back-quote.

Comment: @AFH I'm sorry for forget write keyboard type. Updated my question.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without my own Turkish keyboard, but after trying various soft keyboards I found that `AltGr-,` (comma) seems to work, although the key can be in different positions.

Comment: Thanks @AFH That's great solution for me. I hate copy-paste from charmap :)

Comment: Glad to help. I'll post it as an answer. If you accept it, others will see that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a Turkish keyboard, or even the same key layout, which I could define as Turkish, I have had to test with soft keyboards.

The soft keys are in different positions from your layout, but it seems that `AltGr-,` (comma) generates the back-quote you require.

You may wish to go through your keyboard and make a note of what each key generates when AltGr and AltGr-Shift are held down. You will probably find other useful short-cuts. I went through all my keyboard and found that I have direct access to all the German, Norwegian and French characters that I occasionally need.